# Emoji in strings.xml file?

Tags: android, string, utf-8, emoji

My `string.xml` is utf-8.

```
<string name="id">Hi \u0026</string>
```

^This worked. and showed as: Hi &.

But this does not work with this emoji :

```
<string name="id">Hi \u1F448</string>
```

https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F448

How can I make it work with ?

Comment: this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792856/emoji-symbol-in-string-xml-crashes-app

Comment: @GianhTran I read that link before but I am still not sure one work but the other does not.  Can Android only render 'basic' emoji but not fancier ones?  I don't think so...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use HTML Entity (decimal) i.e. `&#128072;` to add  in `strings.xml` and use it in your app.

So your string will be:

```
<string name="emoji">Hi &#128072;</string>
```

Output:

[image]

For more information please check [**here**](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f448/index.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Using HTML encoding is not working for me, at least when using the HTML code as `&#2764` for the red heart emoji in the translation editor. I copied the unicode number from https://emojipedia.org/emoji/%E2%9D%A4/

However, just pasting it as the emoji character from clipboard ❤️ direct into the translations editor worked just fine, and perhaps I needn't have worried at all.