# Android - Convert Unicode to HTML Entity

Tags: android, unicode, converters

As mentioned in [Emoji in strings.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068120/emoji-in-strings-xml-file) you need to use Unicode smileys like these:

https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

as HTML Entity but why didn't he mentioned how to convert them to HTML Entity.

I tried all kind of online converters like https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-html-entities-convertor.php but they don't convert stuff like U+1F601 to anything.

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier than you might think: U+1F601 corresponds to `&#x1f601;`.

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to Henry's answer, You may use as follows.

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello world! &#128513;</string>
// this is using in decimal
```

But I have found that it is giving run time errors in Lollipop and below.
It works on marshmallow and above.

Comment: But how you get &#128513; from U+1F601 in the first place?

Comment: If you do not wish to do it programmatically then you may visit the following link. You can see the end of string as U+1F601 to convert specific character. This link has "HTML Entity: " section where you can get the decimal converted or hex converted value.      https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F601

Comment: for programatically in java ... int decimal=Integer.parseInt("1F601",16);