# Is it possible to include an emoji in an Android string resource

Tags: android, xml, emoji

I would like to include an emoji in an Android String ressource in an XML file and I wanted to ask if this is possible or not?

I tried the solution suggested in [Emoji in strings.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068120/emoji-in-strings-xml-file):

```
<string name="message">Your rating was submitted successfully. Thank you&#128072;!</string>
```

But this does not work. After "Thank you" nothing is displayed. Any idea how I can change that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emoji in strings.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068120/emoji-in-strings-xml-file)

Comment: @forpas: Thanks for your comment. I had already linked your suggested question and said that it does not help. I tried the solution suggested there but nothing is shown

Answer (score 1):

You can use this website: https://getemoji.com/

Go to this website and you will able to literally copy paste emojis in your string file. (No codes required)